# How to fill Array List with Artist Names of Songs from another Array List

Tags: java, android, arraylist

So I am working on a sample playlist for a music player and I am trying to get Artist Name and Track Titles. I have successfully displayed both of these in a listFragment. However both Artist Names and Title Tracks are in different ArrayLists and are retrieved separately. Therefore when i try to sort one list every thing gets messed up.

Code to retrieve Title

```
public void findAllMusicFilesTitles() {

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE };
    Cursor audioCursor = getActivity().getBaseContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    if (audioCursor != null) {
        while (audioCursor.moveToNext()) {
            songarray.add(audioCursor.getString(audioCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE)));
            }
        audioCursor.close();
    }
}
```

Code to retrieve Artist Names

```
 public void findAllMusicFilesArtists() {

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ARTIST };
    Cursor audioCursor = getActivity().getBaseContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    if (audioCursor != null) {
        while (audioCursor.moveToNext()) {
            artistarray.add(audioCursor.getString(audioCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ARTIST)));
        }
        audioCursor.close();
    }
}
```

The onCreate() method of ListFragment where i do the sorting

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    songarray = new ArrayList<String>();
    artistarray = new ArrayList<String>();

    findAllMusicFilesTitles();
    findAllMusicFilesArtists();

    Collections.sort(songarray, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

    playlistArrayAdapter adapter = new playlistArrayAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), songarray, artistarray);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Can you please suggest a solution to this problem. I had an idea of creating another ArrayList with song URLs and then trying to find a way around but that seems useless as well.

Thank You

Comment: Have you tried a hashmap?

Comment: @JosefE. No, I didn't. I'm new to android development. however i will look into that

Answer (score 1):

You could use the cursor to re-retrieve the information in the database based upon your sorted list of values.

Or you could maintain a Hashmap of your values between one another for quick reference so that it doesn't matter what order they are in when you want something from the other.  After a sort, it just might be wise to re-retrieve data from the database based on your sort though.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a custom wrapper around the song name and artist name. Then use this class as backing model to your adapter, and then have a custom comparator to sort your models based on whatever fields you want to sort on.

```
class PlayerModel {
    private String songName;
    private String artistName;

    // override equals and hashCode.
}
```